# Loading Geodataframe to PostgreSQL with psycopg2 connection

Tags: python, postgresql, geopandas

I have created a Geodataframe from a PostgreSQL table with the following instruction (where 'con' is a psycopg2 connection):

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis("SELECT id, geom FROM {0}".format('pg_table'), con=con, geom_col='geom')
```

I have then processed the Geodataframe and I would like to load the result into a new table in PostgreSQL. However, I don't seem to find an equivalent instruction to 'from_postgis' (something like 'to_postgis' or similar). I have read a post about some SQLAlchemy, which seems over-complicated and I must admit I have not understood. Just wondering whether there's any simple way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method in pandas. If you don't have any spatial datatypes to write you can use it as is. But if you do have spatial datatypes, you'll need [GeoAlchemy](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is an example for writing a geodataframe with `Point` data in a column called `geom`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@server:port/dbname')

gdf.to_sql(
    tablename,
    engine,
    if_exists='append',
    index=False, 
    dtype={
        'geom': Geometry('POINT', srid=4326),
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, May I know what is 'eng'?

Comment: @PitrakoJunior, good question. `eng` is a sqlalchemy [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html). I edited my answer to show how to create it.

Comment: You do not need geoalchemy to insert a spatial table, I do it all the time with psycopg2 without issue.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the clarification. @wfgeo, may we know how you do it with psycopg2?

Comment: @PitrakoJunior Sorry, I am mistaken. I guess I was mistaking all the reading I was doing for writing. A psycopg2 connection on its own is indeed not sufficient for writing a geopandas dataframe into a PostGIS database.

Comment: is there a way to specify just the srid in the dtype but leave the 'POINT' out? I'm having heterogenous shapes, but all in 4326